# axios-mock-adapter If I mock the requests then works only the requests that I mock

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, mocking, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I'm trying to mock API that not implemented on server yet. But if I mock the requests then works only the requests that I mock. If I add `mock.restore();` after `mock.onGet` then real API works fine, but then there is no mock API that I need too.

```
import * as axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

const mainConfig = require('../../../config/main.js');

const request = (axios as any).create({
  baseURL: mainConfig.apiBaseUrl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

const mock = new MockAdapter(request);

mock.onGet('basket').reply(200, {...});

export default request;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [library documentation](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter#example) explains, unmocked requests should be explicitly allowed:

```
// Mock specific requests, but let unmatched ones through
mock
  .onGet('/foo').reply(200)
  .onPut('/bar', { xyz: 'abc' }).reply(204)
  .onAny().passThrough();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Estus answer, we can forward other requests to server as below as well.

```
// Mock all requests to /foo with HTTP 200, 
// but forward any others requests to server
var mock = new MockAdapter(axiosInstance, { onNoMatch: "passthrough" });

mock.onAny("/foo").reply(200);
```